# Why didn’t Eneb Ray reveal Palpatine’s powers?

Tags: star-wars

In *Star Wars Annual 1*, Rebel intelligence agent Eneb Ray foolishly attempts an assassination of Emperor Palpatine, which goes about as well as one might expect:

[image]

Notably, though, he actually *survives*, and shows up in at least one future episode of the *Star Wars* comics. While some (such as Bail Organa) might have had reason to suspect Palpatine’s Sith affiliations, [certainly the information was not widely known.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/122440/51379) Did Eneb Ray ever attempt to inform the Rebellion leadership of Palpatine’s true nature? And if (as it seems) he didn’t, why not?

Comment: I wonder if he simply didn't understand the implications of Palatine shooting lightning from his hands.

Comment: @DBPriGuy - He might not have realized the implications of Palpatine deflecting blaster bolts with his bare hands, or torturing him with Force energy, insofar as Palpatine being Sith, but he surely would have realized that “The Emperor has god-like powers” might be a useful piece of tactical information.

Comment: True, I read your question as Eneb specifically identifying Palpatine as a Sith. Anyways, by similar reasoning as the linked question, I think the argument could be made that he *did* inform the higher-ups in the rebellion, but they chose not to disseminate that information to the rest of the rebellion since it would be more demoralizing than helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**He does.** After being attacked by the Emperor, Ray goes insane, as revealed by the canon comic book *[Star Wars: Rebel Jail, Part III](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_18:_Rebel_Jail,_Part_III)*. He, as well as some IG-RM enforcer droids, attacked the rebellion's Sunspot Prison (named so because it is near a sun). Ray personally attacks many of the station's prisoners in an effort to rid the galaxy of all Imperials.

After attacking an unknown prisoner, he reveals that the Emperor is a Sith Lord to him as the prisoner dies.

[image]

Comment: Did he go insane so fast that he did not have time to warn the Rebel leadership?

Comment: Yeah, pretty much. I don't know the exact amount of time between Star Wars Annual #1 and Rebel Jail, but I think it's all within the same year.